# iOS - Uploading to Vimeo from Application

Tags: ios, video, vimeo

In my iOS application, there's an option to user to upload videos to Vimeo.
I came across a framework 'https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion' which has the option to upload video to Vimeo.
When I ran sample code, it opens safari for vimeo authentication. After successfully authenticating, its not coming back to the application. Can some one help me in identifying the issue of why its not coming back to the app after authorization.
In info.plist file, url scheme is included.
When registering for vimeo application, is it necessary to have "callback URL"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
While creating the application in vimeo, set the call back url like "myapp://something.com"
Then in the urlscheme of the app, you have to set the urlschemes to "myapp"
Note: Use your own label for "myapp" to distinguish the url scheme from other apps.